# Angular SSR Error Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/js/popper.min.js.map'

Tags: angular

Hey im about to deploy an angular web page , so i add , angular universal to improve SEO,
but when i use the local server to see whats going on whith my app it shows an error in the server.

THIS IS THE ERROR

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'as`enter code here`sets/js/popper.min.js.map'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/js/popper.min.js.map'
    at router_ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2823184)
    at catchError_CatchSubscriber.selector (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2822850)
    at catchError_CatchSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2777940)
    at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
    at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1043952)
    at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
    at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1043952)
    at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
    at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1043952)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
    at resolvePromise (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1626993)
    at resolvePromise (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1625970)
    at C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1628797
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1618097)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2106157)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1617987)
    at Zone.runTask (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1610662)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1621705)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1619746)
    at ZoneTask.options.useG.invoke (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1619511) {
  rejection: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/js/popper.min.js.map'
      at router_ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2823184)
      at catchError_CatchSubscriber.selector (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2822850)
      at catchError_CatchSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2777940)
      at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
      at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1043952)
      at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
      at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1043952)
      at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
      at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1043952)
      at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167),
  promise: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
    __zone_symbol__state: 0,
    __zone_symbol__value: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/js/popper.min.js.map'
        at router_ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2823184)
        at catchError_CatchSubscriber.selector (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2822850)
        at catchError_CatchSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:2777940)
        at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
        at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1043952)
        at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
        at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1043952)
        at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
        at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1043952)
        at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Zienen\Proyectos\Revuo\theliverpublicweb\dist\appo\server\main.js:1:1044167)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find out what it was?